# Intermittent Office Wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

Our office is a large and thin rectangle. There is a wifi router that is positioned on one side of the office. The people on the opposite side have full wifi range but spiritually thought the day the internet chugs and disconnects.

Is this a possible solution? Can you take a line from the output of one router and use it to fuel a second? Then we can put the second router on the other side of the office?

[image]

Comment: If you set it up as in your drawing then make sure you do not end up with **two** DHCP servers.   PS: Are those linksys WRT54GL's? (notice the L) or linksys WRT54G V4's? Then look into tomatoe firmware.

Comment: Could I just split the line and send two lines into each router?

Comment: No, Ethernet does not work that way.  You could use a switch, but simply tying to cables into one will not work unless you make sure one of the two devices is always off. And that defeats the entire purpose.

Comment: Could you add the following information to your post: 1) Do you have multiple [public] IPs available? 2) If not, is the first WiFi-router doing NAT? 3) Is the first WiFi-router running a DHCP server? Is the router 2.4GHz or 5Ghz. (human bodies absorb 2.4GHz radiation, which would mean we would advice you to mount the WiFi router above peoples head. 4) Are both the same model? (same models of same manufacturer routers often can work in a team, different brands are often a pain to team up. 5) Which firmware is running in the WiFi routers?

Comment: Your picture shows a LAN port connected to a WAN port. That can't be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add an access point or even a repeater to the network  There are a numnber of different options but don't want to suggest specific brands

Adding another router as you show may be possible but it would need to support being configured as an access point.

You could also look at high gain antennas.

You also need a site survey to make sure there is not a device nearby that is on the same channel.  This is a common issue.   Often finding a little used channel and setting the router to that will help.  Most are configured to select a channel automatically.  Here is a common tool you can download[Heatmapper](http://www.ekahau.com/products/heatmapper/overview.html)

Also look for traffic that causes the slowdown and disconnects.  Someone streaming something or a large download could have an impact

Comment: dave, how can someone find out which channel has the least traffic?

Comment: If you run windows that I found inSSIDer useful for that task. (just one example of many programs able to do that)  http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/

Comment: See edit for one tool